# Trigger Monitor in JMS Provider like MQ Series

Tags: jms, qpid, jboss-messaging, openjms, sonicmq

In Websphere MQ I can configure a Queue to Trigger an Application when a message arrives.
In that way I can have an Application that starts only if needs and I don't have to manage one daemon that wait for message in that queue.
More information about [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026910_.htm)

Are There an open source JMS Provider that bring this functionality?

I tried ActiveMQ but it hasn't triggers.

Comment: Suggest you tag your question so experts in other JMS providers see it, as you've only tagged it for websphere-MQ and you already know the answer for that one :-)

Comment: @MoragHughson Thanks, I added those that exist..

Comment: Doesn't websphere MQ just send a new message to a trigger queue when there is a message in the main queue? How is that different from starting your real application thread from the onMessage method of a "trigger" thread? onMessage is part of JMS, so all the JMS clients implement it. You could even have a trigger client generate a new trigger message in a new queue if that is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @RaGe yes, it's seems acceptable. Could you try to explain in an answer? maybe with some reference? When arrives a message and myApplication is still in execution, WMQ doen't launch it again, it's supposed that the user application consume all messagges in the queue.Can I expect similar behavior? Or all messages call "onMessage"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qpid does not have a websphere-MQ like monitor trigger feature. I know ActiveMQ doesn't either, and I suspect this may be true of other JMS providers as well. However, it is possible to roll out your own monitor-trigger.

A homebrew monitor-trigger would then become an application process(albeit light-lightweight) that you will have to manage though, would you be better off managing an actual application thread itself?

---

#### To implement a monitor trigger in qpid:

JMS spec defines an [asynchronous delivery mode. See section 4.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf). So you should be able to do this with any JMS provider. An [asynchronous listener](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfh/index.html) implements the `javax.jms.MessageListener` interface. The method `onMessage()` needs to be implemented and serves as the callback function when any new message appears on the queue it is subscribed to.

Suppose the main application queue is `mainQ`. You create a new `MessageListener` for `mainQ`, in browse mode - so as to not actually consume any messages from mainQ

```
Destination mainQ = (Destination) session.createQueue("mainQ; {mode: browse}");
MessageConsumer mainQConsumer = session.createConsumer(mainQ);
mainQConsumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

In the `onMessage()` function you can either create a new message in a separate `triggerQ` or you can skip this step and get right to starting up the application.

```
public void onMessage(Message message)
{
  TextMessage triggerMessage = session.createTextMessage("Trigger-start-Application-X");

  Destination triggerQ = (Destination) session.createQueue("triggerQ");
  triggerQProducer = session.createProducer(triggerQ);
  this.triggerQProducer.send(triggerMessage);

  // Or alternatively:
  // if (!applicationIsActive()) activateApplication()
}
```

See full working sample here: https://github.com/foragerr/qpid-trigger-demo